# setcookie php very slow or what happened?

Tags: php, cookies, localhost, session-cookies

This is a small test. I set a cookie and then try to access it:

```
<?php 
setcookie("t",0,time()+900);    
echo ($_COOKIE['t']+10);
setcookie("t",0,time()-3600);   
?>
```

When I run the code I get an error message as below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: t in /var/www/x/testcookie.php on line 5
10
```

Why can't I access the cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. `setcookie` just says "with next http connection tell client (browser) to set this cookie. The browser sends it back in next http connection, if it has not expired yet. Only then it is contained in `$_COOKIE` array. So you can check that it is set in PHP after next page reload.

Besides in your code second cookie will not be set, because you outputted something to the browser which is forbidden before `setcookie` function (any header function).

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.
>
> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

you need understand how cookies works. with setcookie you sent header to browser, which tells browser to store cookie. And $_COOKIE superglobal contains cookies which comes from user request headers. so it means that variable which you set with setcookie only be available in $_COOKIE array after refresh, when it comes back with user request headers. And remember that set headers you can only before any output, so second setcookie will not work.